# abusing notation ? What does that mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

[image]

I am trying to study lineair algebra on my self, and I came across a weird phenomenom "abusing a notation" What do they mean by that , does that mean that it isnt mathematical correct? Or is it a connection that doesn't really have meaning?

Comment: Hard to say, unless you specifically provide background.  For example, what is the exact wording of the source document's definition of a function?

Comment: I expect that they are distinguishing between writing "$P(z)=z^m$" and simply "$z^m"$.  The "function" should be $P$ in what I wrote, but it is standard to just write $z^m$.

Comment: Your last three questions all contained pictures of text. I want to urge you to replace them by actual text with formulas typeset using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The reason is that pictures of text are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Its a lot easier this way. Right know im focused on math and learning MathJax will be a chore. I will look into it in the future

Comment: See the Wikipedia article on [Abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation).

Comment: Good call , My teachers have always hammered on it to not use wikipedia , damn teachers

Comment: @OogwaysStaf: Wikipedia is mostly accurate on mathematical topics. It gets a bad rap for no reason. By the way, if you want to notify me when you comment then you should begin your comment with ``@Joe``.

Comment: @Joe thats handy , thnx mate :D

Comment: @OogwaysStaf: It worked! :)

Comment: @OogwaysStaf You're expected to put in some effort in writing and formatting your questions when you expect others to put in the effort to provide help and answers.

Comment: @Christoph Thats true , but when I am studying something I am not going to get distracted a learn MathJax. I will surely make time for it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means I think that it is not technically accurate to describe $z^k$ as a "function", as it is really a polynomial, i.e a formal expression involving powers of $k$. There is a technical distinction to be made between a polynomial and the corresponding function, but they often can be regarded as the same thing. I am not sure how clear my explanation is to you, but basically the comment in the text can be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, if $f(z) = z^k$, then the function is $f$, not $z^k$.  But going through the contortions to add another layer of notation would only obscure the plain meaning.  So since "we all know" that by $z^k$, we mean the function $z \mapsto z^k$, then let's just write $z^k$.

This depends on what definition for "function" your text actually uses, so I'm guessing a little bit here.